# Query document for record with array value of null

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "4mDYgt6gID",
    ...
    "MultipleChoiceQuestions" : [ 
        {
            ...
            "LeadInFile" : null,
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
            "LeadInFile" : 'some string',
            ...
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

How do I query for any documents that have a non-null value in `LeadInFile`?

I'm trying different things, currently something like this
`db.getCollection('QuizTime:Quizzes').find({"MultipleChoiceQuestions": [{ "LeadInFile": { $ne: null}}]});`

Is returning 0 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current form of the query is saying:

> Find documents where `MultipleChoiceQuestions` is `[{ "LeadInFile": { $ne: null}}]`

Try using [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation); this is used to access elements of an array or fields in an embedded document. For example:

```
db.getCollection('QuizTime:Quizzes').find({
  "MultipleChoiceQuestions.LeadinFile" : { "$ne" : null }
})
```

Comment: Upvote for also explaining what my attempt was doing